# JQuery Append() Need to create two Bootstrap columns by looping an associative array key and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a form with label and inputs, I've an associative array which has the label in "key" and values in the array Object value.

I want to create a bootstrap horizontal form with 2 columns (col-6) and (col-6), unfortunately I'm not able to do so.

Here is an example array:

UserArray: {
"id": "15",
"first_name": "abc",
"last_name": "xyz",
"address": "Address",
"zipcode": "111"
}

I want to create the bootstrap layout as below through jQuery append() method.

**OUTPUT REQUIRED**

```
<div class="col-12">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4"> ID </label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4"> First Name </label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4"> Last Name </label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4"> Address </label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4"> Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" class="col-md-8">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- NOTE THERE IS NO SECOND COLUMNS HERE SINCE ONLY 5 OBJECTS IN ARRAY -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

To get this layout, I'm only using the jQuery as below using the forloop.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

const userArray = { "id": "15", "first_name": "abc", "last_name": "xyz", "address": "Address", "zipcode": "111" };
var arrayLength = Object.keys(userArray);

var counter = 0; //initializing this counter just to know which object the loop is.
var columnBlock = ''; //will append this to an element in HTML.

columnBlock += '<form class="horizontal-form">

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  if(counter == 0 || counter %2 == 0) {
    columnBlock += '<div class="row"';
      columnBlock += '<div class="col-md-6">;
         columnBlock += '<div class="form-group row">; 
           columnBlock += '<label class="col-md-4">'+Object.keys(userArray);+'</label>';
           columnBlock += '<input class="col-md-8 form-control" value="'+Object.values(userArray)+'">';
         columnBlock += '</div>'; //form-group close
      columnBlock += '</div>'; //col-6 close
    columnBlock += '</div>'; //row close
  }
 // HERE NO ROWS ONLY COLUMN COL-6, SINCE IT IS THE SECOND COL. IT's NOT WORKING! 
  columnBlock += '<div class="col-md-6">;
  columnBlock += '<div class="form-group row">; 
  columnBlock += '<label class="col-md-4">'+Object.keys(userArray);+'</label>';
  columnBlock += '<input class="col-md-8 form-control" value="'+Object.values(userArray)+'">';
  columnBlock += '</div>'; //form-group close
  columnBlock += '</div>'; //col-6 close
 
  counter = counter + 1;
 } // For Close 
$("#info-blok").append(columnBlock); // here appending to HTML div block
}); // JQUERY CLOSE
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="" id="info-blok"> </div>
```

It's not working, can anyone please guide me like how to get the output that has two columns, also note that the last row has just one column.

The output I'm getting is just one column with row and the next column with just "col-6".

Thanks

Comment: `columnBlock += '<form class="horizontal-form">` you forgot to close the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you probably didn't want someone to rewrite your logic, but in editing your code I found enough errors (or confusion) that i thought this was a good teaching moment. The way I approached this was to stage the data, first by creating the form element blocks, and then assigning them to col-md-6 or col-md-12. It makes it more bite size and easy to read.

To loop through the userArray, I used `Object.entries(userArray)` which converts `{id:123, first_name:"john"}` into the array `[['id','123'],['first_name','john']]` -  which is desirable because we need to iterate through it.

Iterating through that object, I chose to use `map()`. `map()` allows us to transform the array data, item by item, which means we can return the finished HTML block for each iteration.

Then a second `map()` to put in our col-md-6/12 classes. I could have conbined these 2, but thought it was more legible with them separate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const userArray = {
    "id": "15",
    "first_name": "abc",
    "last_name": "xyz",
    "address": "Address",
    "zipcode": "111"
  };
  let arrayLength = Object.keys(userArray).length;
  let counter = 0; //initializing this counter just to know which object the loop is.
  let formItems = Object.entries(userArray).map(e => {
    return `<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-4">${e[0]}</label>
  <input class="col-md-8 form-control" placeholder="${e[0]}" value="${e[1]}"></div>`;
  }).map((e, i) => {
    let cl = (i === arrayLength - 1 && i % 2 === 0) ? "col-md-12" : "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6";
    return `<div class="${cl}">${e}</div>`;
  }).join('');

  formItems = `<form class="horizontal-form"><div class="row">${formItems}</div></form>`;
  $("#info-blok").append(formItems); // here appending to HTML div block
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="" id="info-blok"> </div>
```